# What's the fastest way to search for a value in json in SQL, if we do not know the path

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am looking for the fastest way to search in a SQL table for a value in a JSON.

I am trying to update this value. And there may be more occurrences in the same JSON.

```
update d
    set d.Content = replace(d.Content, rm.WrongValue , rm.NewValue)
    from dbo.Document d
    inner join RenameMatches rm d.content like '%' + rm.WrongValue + '%'
```

The next line is taking to long and I am trying to make it faster

```
 d.content like '%' + rm.WrongValue + '%'
```

I thought using JSON_Modify, however, the path is not always the same.

Thanks!

Comment: *Assuming* you are using a fully supported version of SQL Server, it has out of the box JSON support. If you're not, perhaps it's time you made sure you were.

Comment: With a variable path this is not going to be a fast operation, no matter what. Full-text searching is inefficient since it's not amenable to indexing (while full-text search is a separate feature, it doesn't work very well on anything that's not natural language). If the number of different paths is at least limited (not completely variable), you can [index on computed expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/json/index-json-data).

Answer (score 0):

If there's multiple WrongValue's in that RenameMatches, then you could loop through them.

But then it needs some sequencial number without gaps.

In the example below, the values are assumed to be strings.
So they get double-quoted to match complete string values.

**Demo:**

> ```
> -- 
> -- Sample data
> -- 
> create table Document (
>  document_id int identity primary key, 
>  content nvarchar(max)
> );
>
> insert into Document (content) values
>   ('[{"id":1, "code":"abc123"},{"id":2, "code":"def456"}]') 
> , ('{"id":3, "data":{"name":"test",code1":"abc123","code2":"abc123"}}');
>
> create table RenameMatches (
>  WrongValue nvarchar(30) not null primary key, 
>  NewValue nvarchar(30) not null
> );
>
> insert into RenameMatches (WrongValue, NewValue) values
>   ('abc123', 'abc12345')
> , ('def456', 'def456789');
> ```

> ```
> -- Using a table variable with identity
> DECLARE @RenameMatches table (
>  id INT identity primary key, 
>  WrongValue NVARCHAR(30) not null, 
>  NewValue NVARCHAR(30) not null
> );
>
> INSERT INTO @RenameMatches (WrongValue, NewValue) 
> SELECT WrongValue, NewValue
> FROM RenameMatches;
>
> DECLARE @MaxRenameID INT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @RenameMatches);
> DECLARE @RenameID INT = 1;
>
> WHILE @RenameID <= @MaxRenameID
> BEGIN
>    UPDATE d
>    SET d.Content = REPLACE(d.Content
>                    , quotename(rm.WrongValue,'"') 
>                    , quotename(rm.NewValue,'"')) 
>    FROM Document d
>    JOIN @RenameMatches rm
>      ON rm.id = @RenameID 
>     AND d.content like '%"'+rm.WrongValue+'"%';
>
>    SET @RenameID += 1;
> END;
> ```

> ```
> select * from Document
> ```

| document_id | content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"id":1, "code":"abc12345"},{"id":2, "code":"def456789"}] |
| 2 | {"id":3, "data":{"name":"test",code1":"abc12345","code2":"abc12345"}} |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=10dae956b0a5b46ce9d422a15b784258)*